# python3.6: equivalent of %d %s using the format: f("string {var1} {var2})

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

Look at the syntax of the print:

```
for index, link in enumerate(links):
   args = (index, link.xpath('@href').extract(), 
   link.xpath('img/@src').extract())
   print ('Link number %d points to url %s and image %s' % args)
```

This code works in python 3.6. It sends:

```
Link number 0 points to url [u'image1.html'] and image [u'image1_thumb.jpg']
```

but is there an equivalent using f"...{var}" ?

---

It would look like this one which doesnt work:

```
print (f'Link number {repr(enumerate)} points to url {str(index)} and image {str(link)}')
```

send:

```
Link number 0 points to url <Selector xpath='//a[contains(@href, "image")]' data='<a href
="image1.html">Name: My image 1 <'>
```

You can see the full code in this [scrapy](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#nesting-selectors) tuto.

Comment: Why not `print(f'Link number {index} points to url {link}')` - you're either trying to over-complicate it or I'm missing what the question is...

Comment: because it sends: `Link number 0 points to url <Selector xpath='//a[contains(@href, "image")]' data='<a href
="image1.html">Name: My image 1 <'>` (I edited the question, thanks for asking!)

Comment: So the next question is - why are you trying to make this an f-string? Creating the args you want and then just doing what you're doing - or maybe even just `str.format` is clear - you can re-use the vars afterwards etc...

Comment: @JonClements True, it was just by curiosity and because I finf the f".." much easier to read (the %d syntax code works in 3.6).

Comment: It's easier to read for *some cases* - sure... attempting to pile in what you've got there is well... *ugh*... plus - if you want to do something with those later, you've still gotta create yours args anyway... so you're doubling up the work for less readability...

Comment: But anyway... I'd go for `print('Link number {} points to url {} and image {}'.format(*args))`...

Comment: @JonClements Thanks! I understand your point. Your last comment answers my question, please post it so I could choose it as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @JonClements, here is the answer:

```
print('Link number {} points to url {} and image {}'.format(*args))
```